# How to create a file with its name starting with dash in Linux? (ex "-file")

Tags: shell, command-line, touch

How can I create a file named "-file" using command line in Linux?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ls -ltr | awk '$NF ~ /^--/{print "rm ./" $NF}'|sh
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: thanx a lot! :)

Answer (score 20):

specify a path in front of it, e.g. `./-file`

Comment: that is what I need!

Answer (score 20):

In bash `--` is a flag that is interpreted as "nothing after this should be taken as a flag", so `-` is no longer parsed as an option.

```
touch -- -file
```